# Remove elements with same data-id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pattern like that:

```
<section>
    <div data-id="39"></div>
    <div data-id="31"></div>
    <div data-id="57"></div>
    <div data-id="10"></div>
    <div data-id="27"></div>
    <div data-id="5"></div>
    <div data-id="89"></div>
</section>
```

That contains some data that are live updated via AJAX. Sometimes, it may happen to receive from the server a data updated with the same id of another one in the section, and since it's the same id, I need to remove the old data to avoid multiple datas and keep just the updated one.

For example, I receive an update with `data-id` 27 and I insert at the top:

```
<section>
    <div data-id="27"></div>
    <div data-id="39"></div>
    <div data-id="31"></div>
    <div data-id="57"></div>
    <div data-id="10"></div>
    <div data-id="27"></div>
    <div data-id="5"></div>
    <div data-id="89"></div>
</section>
```

After inserted it, how can I do a check that if 27 is already available in the section (so the last iteration), remove it from the section? Basically removing all the data with the same id and keep just the one at the top.

Comment: What have you tried so far? All you have shows is a bit of HTML?

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve this yourself. Remember that SO is here to help you debug code, not write it for you. To give you some research topics, you need an attribute selector, `not()`, `:first` and `remove()`

Comment: Why not check to make sure element doesn't already exist before blindly inserting it into your section?

Comment: What I have to try? Did you read at least the question? I'm asking for a 3 line code after I wrote the whole task (more than 200 lines of code) because I didn't find any function that helps me do that. I didn't ask to build for me the whole task, I just showed the context in which I find myself, but I could just say "remove elements with multiple data-id". It was just to make clearer my problem, I think you have exaggerated a little with that downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very inspired at the moment but with the amount of info you game us i made this example with jquery. It can be done also  just with plain javaScript if needed

```js
$('div').each(function() {
  dataId = $(this).data('id');
  otherDataId = $(this).siblings().data('id');
  if (otherDataId === dataId) {
   $(this).hide()
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
    <div data-id="27">27</div>
    <div data-id="39">1</div>
    <div data-id="31">2</div>
    <div data-id="57">3</div>
    <div data-id="10">4</div>
    <div data-id="27">27</div>
    <div data-id="5">5</div>
    <div data-id="89">6</div>
</section>
```

Comment: You don't need the loop: `$(\`div[data-id="${newId}"]:not(:first)\`).remove();`

Comment: Thank you for both, I didn't know about these functions. I was needing just for an input like that, I don't know if it's how I asked the question or the question it's totally off topic, but I never asked for the whole code here in SO but just helps in parts that I don't find answers on other questions. I'm sorry to have unleashed some repressed soul.

Comment: Btw, both works, but @Mihai T snippet support also multiple data and it's more flexible if I get more than one data to update the section. Thanks again.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes. That has been my signature bad practice for a while now :)) I guess i just love loops. I need to stop doing that where is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try creating a function to remove the element with the specific `data-id` value you want like this:

```
const removeItems = (number) => {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-id="${number}"]`);
    elements.forEach((e) => { e.remove() });
};
```

And then to remove elements with `data-id=27` you can do: `removeItems(27);`.

Take a look:

```js
const removeItems = (number) => {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(`div[data-id="${number}"]`);
    elements.forEach((e) => { e.remove() });
};
removeItems(27);
```

```html
<section>
    <div data-id="27">27</div>
    <div data-id="39">39</div>
    <div data-id="31">31</div>
    <div data-id="57">57</div>
    <div data-id="10">10</div>
    <div data-id="27">27</div>
    <div data-id="5">5</div>
    <div data-id="89">89</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelector(`[data-id=${myDataId}]`).remove();
```

Comment: I believe the `${myDataId}` needs quotes around it to be a valid selector. This also just removes the first element of that type (the one OP wanted to keep) and leaves any others in place (the ones OP wants to remove).

Comment: Works without quotes. Verified on this page using `document.querySelector('[class=adsbox]')`

Comment: This can be called before the new element is inserted.